# This simple MySQL query is returning an empty result set

Tags: mysql

My query is returning an empty result set, even when I test for hidden spaces:

```
SELECT * FROM `wager_DB` WHERE `outcome`='Lose';
```

And

```
SELECT * FROM `wager_DB` WHERE `outcome`='%Lose%';
```

Both return an empty set. Anybody have any ideas?

Here is a CSV export of my wager_DB:

```
"Pdinkle";"1";"12";"Lose
";"2";"2015-04-06 19:19:05";"24"
"TrustingMeerkat";"1";"6";"Win
";"5";"2015-04-06 19:19:43";"30"
```

Comment: Maybe you have no records which have `outcome='Lose'`. Kindly, show to us your table schema and some values.

Comment: Can I accurately show you my table without inadvertently removing any white space or empty space that might otherwise be there? I'm using phpMyAdmin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When using `%` use `LIKE` instead of `=` so try:

```
SELECT * FROM wager_DB WHERE outcome LIKE '%Lose%';
```

Comment: That worked, why is my query result LIKE the actual one?

Comment: the syntax for LIKE '%something%' will pull everything will contain something on it, maybe you have some empty space hidden somewhere before or after ```Lose```?

Comment: I don't think it does, there is no alteration to the actual value after it's inserted into the table. Even if it does have empty spaces (or something along those lines) Wouldn't it carry through my code and still work?
EDIT* I should clarify that I reference the outcome through pages using hidden post variables or even session variables. The actual value is never changed.

Answer (score 0):

There was hidden whitespace after my value. I found this in the form of '\n' further back through my code. Thanks for all the responses, I learnt a lot.